# Set XZ origin to objects

Tags: origin

I have a map splitted to 256 chunks, now I need to center origin to every object, but I need to center only X and Z origin, not Y.
Or another way, can I change Y origin to 0 for all objects?

[image]

Comment: You mean XZ  as shown? Halfway up the hills, halfway along the bottom, on the left edge?